# Circumvent "Resources can only be opened for reading" in flask

Tags: python, flask

Using `app.open_resource('foobar.txt', 'w')` generates the error `Resources can only be opened for reading` in flask.

Is there a way to open a resource to write to it?

If not, can you get the path of the resource using flask and then I can open it manually and write to it.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Resources are part of the Flask application - you almost certainly don't want to change the application while you're running it.

Comment: If you just want to open a file to write to it, use the standard python: f = open("filename.txt", "w").

Comment: @sigurdga The file could be in another directory relative to the script opening it, so only `open_resource` will work.

Comment: @Tyilo Relative paths works fine for normal open: f = open("../filename.txt", "w")

Comment: @sigurdga `app.open_resource('foobar.txt')` works, but `open('foobar.txt')` returns a file not found error as the directory structure is like a module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
import os
f = open(os.path.join(app.root_path, 'foobar.txt'), 'w')
```

This is more convenient:

```
import os
with open(os.path.join(app.root_path, 'foobar.txt'), 'w') as f:
    ...
```